# Storing objects conforming to a protocol with generics in a typed array

Tags: ios, swift, generics, protocols, generic-collections

I've got a protocol:

```
protocol Adjustable: Equatable {
    associatedtype T
    var id: String { get set }
    var value: T { get set }
    init(id: String, value: T)
}
```

And a struct that conforms to it:

```
struct Adjustment: Adjustable {
    static func == (lhs: Adjustment, rhs: Adjustment) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    typealias T = CGFloat
    var id: String
    var value: T
}
```

And I'm building a wrapper class that behaves like a `Set` to handle an ordered list of these properties:

```
struct AdjustmentSet {
    var adjustmentSet: [Adjustable] = []
    func contains<T: Adjustable>(_ item: T) -> Bool {
        return adjustmentSet.filter({ $0.id == item.id }).first != nil
    }
}

let brightness = Adjustment(id: "Brightness", value: 0)

let set = AdjustmentSet()
print(set.contains(brightness))
```

But that of course doesn't work, erroring with:

> error: protocol 'Adjustable' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements
>           var adjustmentSet: [Adjustable] = []

Looking around, I thought at first this was because the protocol doesn't conform to `Equatable`, but then I added it, and it still doesn't work (or I did it wrong).

Moreover, I would like to be able to use a generic here, so that I can do something like:

```
struct Adjustment<T>: Adjustable {
    static func == (lhs: Adjustment, rhs: Adjustment) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }

    var id: String
    var value: T
}

let brightness = Adjustment<CGFloat>(id: "Brightness", value: 0)
```

Or:

```
struct FloatAdjustment: Adjustable {
    static func == (lhs: Adjustment, rhs: Adjustment) -> Bool {
        return lhs.id == rhs.id
    }
    typealias T = CGFloat
    var id: String
    var value: T
}

let brightness = FloatAdjustment(id: "Brightness", value: 0)
```

And still be able to store an array of `[Adjustable]` types, so that eventually I can do:

```
var set = AdjustmentSet()
if set.contains(.brightness) {
    // Do something!
}
```

Or

```
var brightness = ...
brightness.value = 1.5
set.append(.brightness)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can't have an array of items of type `Adjustable`, because `Adjustable` isn't really a type. It's a blue print that describes a set of types, one per every possible value of `T`.

To get around this, you need to use a type eraser https://medium.com/dunnhumby-data-science-engineering/swift-associated-type-design-patterns-6c56c5b0a73a

Comment: Care to include an example in your answer in case the article goes away?

Comment: (And holy crap this would be a lot easier if we could just enforce that array elements conform to a protocol)

Comment: @brandonscript I don't have the time to type it up. I wasn't sure if I should post this as a comment or an answer.

Comment: @brandonscript And yeah, it would be. There's long-awaited feature called ["Generalized Existentials"](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/docs/GenericsManifesto.md#generalized-existentials)

Answer (score 2):

Have made some great progress using Alexander's suggestion; I was able to use some nested class types to inherit the base type erasure class, and use a generic protocol that conforms to `AnyHashable` so I can use this with a set!

```
// Generic conforming protocol to AnyHashable
protocol AnyAdjustmentProtocol {
    func make() -> AnyHashable
}

protocol AdjustmentProtocol: AnyAdjustmentProtocol {
    associatedtype A
    func make() -> A
}

struct AdjustmentTypes {
    internal class BaseType<T>: Hashable {

        static func == (lhs: AdjustmentTypes.BaseType<T>, rhs: AdjustmentTypes.BaseType<T>) -> Bool {
            return lhs.name == rhs.name
        }

        typealias A = T

        var hashValue: Int { return name.hashValue }

        let name: String
        let defaultValue: T
        let min: T
        let max: T
        var value: T

        init(name: String, defaultValue: T, min: T, max: T) {
            self.name = name
            self.defaultValue = defaultValue
            self.min = min
            self.max = max
            self.value = defaultValue
        }
    }

    class FloatType: BaseType<CGFloat> { }

    class IntType: BaseType<Int> { }
}

struct AnyAdjustmentType<A>: AdjustmentProtocol, Hashable {
    static func == (lhs: AnyAdjustmentType<A>, rhs: AnyAdjustmentType<A>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.hashValue == rhs.hashValue
    }

    private let _make: () -> AnyHashable
    private let hashClosure:() -> Int

    var hashValue: Int {
        return hashClosure()
    }

    init<T: AdjustmentProtocol & Hashable>(_ adjustment: T) where T.A == A {
        _make = adjustment.make
        hashClosure = { return adjustment.hashValue }
    }
    func make() -> AnyHashable {
        return _make()
    }
}

struct Brightness: AdjustmentProtocol, Hashable {
    func make() -> AnyHashable {
        return AdjustmentTypes.FloatType(name: "Brightness", defaultValue: 0, min: 0, max: 1)
    }
}
struct WhiteBalance: AdjustmentProtocol, Hashable {
    func make() -> AnyHashable {
        return AdjustmentTypes.IntType(name: "White Balance", defaultValue: 4000, min: 3000, max: 7000)
    }
}

let brightness = Brightness().make()
let whiteBalance = WhiteBalance().make()

var orderedSet = Set<AnyHashable>()

orderedSet.insert(brightness)
print(type(of: orderedSet))
print(orderedSet.contains(brightness))

for obj in orderedSet {
    if let o = obj as? AdjustmentTypes.FloatType {
        print(o.value)
    }
    if let o = obj as? AdjustmentTypes.IntType {
        print(o.value)
    }
}
```

**Prints:**

```
Set<AnyHashable>
true
0.0
```

Special thanks to this article: https://medium.com/@chris_dus/type-erasure-in-swift-84480c807534 which had a simple and clean example on how to implement a generic type eraser.

Answer (score 1):

With Swift 5.7 you will be able to this without any error from the compiler by prefixing your protocol with `any`, so your set becomes:

```swift
struct AdjustmentSet {
    var adjustmentSet: [any Adjustable] = []
    func contains(_ item: some Adjustable) -> Bool {
        return adjustmentSet.first { $0.id == item.id } != nil
    }
}
```

Note that all items in your `adjustmentSet` array will be allocated on heap since compile time swift can't determine the size of existential type `Adjustable` as types implementing it will have variable size.