# Storing and retrieving class type as string in a Swift array, then casting a generic to known class string

Tags: arrays, swift, generics

I'm continuing my journey to discover the love and hate for Swift's generics, and in the end, I'm still struggling with a fundamental flaw that I can't get around: when storing a generic in an array (even with [fancy type erasure](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54846643/1214800)), I still need to explicitly cast the resulting value in the array to a known type before I can get or set properties in the array.

I know the type, but the only way I can seem to store it, is by the string name of the class (since you can't make an array of types it seems). Maybe there is a proper way to code/decode the type so it can be stored in an array? I tried with `NSClassFromString`, but didn't get very far.

Here is a playground that illustrates the challenge:

```
enum Apple: String {
    case braeburn
    case macintosh
    case honeycrisp
}

protocol AppleProtocol {
    var brand: Apple { get set }
}

protocol AppleGetter {
    func getApple<T>(for key: Apple) -> T?
}

protocol PropertyReflectable { }

extension PropertyReflectable {
    subscript(key: String) -> Any? {
        let m = Mirror(reflecting: self)
        return m.children.first { $0.label == key }?.value
    }
}

struct GenericApple<T: Equatable>: AppleProtocol, Hashable {

    static func == (lhs: GenericApple<T>, rhs: GenericApple<T>) -> Bool {
        return lhs.brand == rhs.brand
    }

    var hashValue: Int { return brand.hashValue }

    var brand: Apple
    var generic: T

    init(brand: Apple, generic: T) {
        self.brand = brand
        self.generic = generic
    }
}

struct Apples {

    typealias Braeburn = GenericApple<Int>
    var braeburn = Braeburn(brand: .braeburn, generic: 10)

    typealias Honeycrisp = GenericApple<String>
    var honeycrisp = Honeycrisp(brand: .honeycrisp, generic: "A generic")
}

extension Apples: PropertyReflectable {
    func getApple<T>(for key: Apple, type: T.Type) -> T? {
        return self[key.rawValue] as? T
    }
}
```

This works great!

```
var applesSet = Apples()

var braeburn = applesSet.getApple(for: Apple.braeburn, type: Apples.Braeburn.self)
braeburn?.generic = 14
print(braeburn?.generic)
```

But what if I want to do:

```
struct AppleListElement {
    let brand: Apple
    let type: String
}

var apples = [AppleListElement]()
apples.append(AppleListElement(brand: .braeburn, type: "\(Apples.Braeburn.self)"))
apples.append(AppleListElement(brand: .honeycrisp, type: "\(Apples.Honeycrisp.self)"))

apples.forEach {
    applesSet.getApple(for: $0.brand, type: NSClassFromString($0.type))
}
```

Comment: I've been following this series of questions, and I keep meaning to come up with a good way to express that you're on the wrong road. You're in the classic trap of trying to over-generic Swift. You're going to be burned again and again. The linked answer is "correct" but also the wrong approach. The main use of AnyHashable is for bridging to ObjC. Use of it in normal Swift is a sign that something has gone wrong. The right answer highly depends on your exact problem, which is probably too complex for a SO question, but it's definitely time to go back to the root problem.

Comment: The fundamental problem I think you're running into is misunderstanding what type inference means. It doesn't mean the type is unknown until runtime. It means the type is obvious to the compiler, so you don't have to include it in the code (but you *could* include it in the code; you just don't *have* to because it's obvious to the compiler). In your code above what would the unambiguous, known-at-compile-time type of your calls to `getApple` be? If it were `let x: SomeType = appleSet...`, what would you put for "SomeType" that is exactly one constant value, not based on any runtime info?

Comment: When you type-erase, you mean "the specific type is unnecessary and should be discarded." You can't get types back from a type eraser (that's why it's a type-eraser not a type-masker). Also, if you're using Mirror, you're probably on a bad road. Swift has very weak reflection, and if you reach for Mirror, you will almost always be disappointed.

Comment: Yeah, that’s exactly the same conclusion I’ve reached. But in the end, I need to store some very similar data types - that conform to some basic structure (protocol, whatever), and display their values in a table view, and update them and make changes. If I’m completely on the wrong track, what even is the right track? Storing all the values as a string and parsing them with a regex seems just as ridiculous 

Comment: It depends on the exact problem. I've build generic form engines; they range from pretty simple to very complicated depending on the exact specs (I generally do this on a consulting basis because it's too big for SO). If there is a small number of types and you're unlikely to add many more, that's different than if there's a large number of types or they need to be arbitrarily added in the future without changing the engine. The usual mistake is trying to solve the most general version of the problem, rather than the problem actually before you.

Comment: With 4 types, that sounds like an enum, not a class. (That's what I started to build for you yesterday, but it was taking too long and I wasn't certain what the actual problem was, so I let it be.)

Comment: Maybe, do I cast a value to the type of the enum? I’ll still need the ability to get and set a value of the property.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189019/discussion-between-rob-napier-and-brandonscript).

Comment: @RobNapier we should circle back now that I've got a working solution; I'd like to give you credit for the answer since you ultimately led me down that path!